# SQL Make a New Colum instead of new Row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm new to the SQL Server subject and I'm not sure how to solve my problem. I have 2 tables that I like to join based on two values of each table.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL, 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.SUCHWORT, 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTTEXT, 
    dbo.FDDATEN.INHALT AS Herstellername,
    dbo.FDDATEN.INHALT AS Typennummer,
    dbo.FDDATEN.INHALT AS Bestellnummer,
    dbo.FDDATEN.INHALT AS HerstArt,
    dbo.FDDATEN.SCHLUESSEL, 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.ROWART
FROM 
    dbo.ARTIKEL
INNER JOIN 
    FDDATEN ON ARTIKEL.ROWART = FDDATEN.SCHLUESSEL 
WHERE 
    ARTIKEL LIKE 'E%'
```

This works and returns something like this:

| ARTIKEL | SUCHWORT | ARTTEXT | Herstellername | Typennummer | Bestellnummer | HerstArt | SCHLUESSEL | ROWART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E220324W001 | C300-02400041A10100A | Commander C300, AC drive, Frame Size 2, 3PH, 400V, 4.1A, 1.5kW % | NCT.C300-02400041A10100AB100 | NCT.C300-02400041A10100AB100 | NCT.C300-02400041A10100AB100 | NCT.C300-02400041A10100AB100 | 236324 | 236324 |
| E220324W001 | C300-02400041A10100A | Commander C300, AC drive, Frame Size 2, 3PH, 400V, 4.1A, 1.5kW % | C300-02400041A10100AB100 | C300-02400041A10100AB100 | C300-02400041A10100AB100 | C300-02400041A10100AB100 | 236324 | 236324 |
| E220324W001 | C300-02400041A10100A | Commander C300, AC drive, Frame Size 2, 3PH, 400V, 4.1A, 1.5kW % | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 236324 | 236324 |
| E220324W001 | C300-02400041A10100A | Commander C300, AC drive, Frame Size 2, 3PH, 400V, 4.1A, 1.5kW % | Nidec | Nidec | Nidec | Nidec | 236324 | 236324 |

But I want it like this way:

| ARTIKEL | SUCHWORT | ARTTEXT | Herstellername | Typennummer | Bestellnummer | HerstArt | SCHLUESSEL | ROWART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E220324W001 | C300-02400041A10100A | Commander C300, AC drive, Frame Size 2, 3PH, 400V, 4.1A, 1.5kW % | NCT.C300-02400041A10100AB100 | C300-02400041A10100AB100 | 1 | Nidec | 236324 | 236324 |

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the logic here? Showing us the expected results with no explanation doesn't help us help you.

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Use table aliases instead of full table names.

Comment: You're selecting the same column (dbo.FDDATEN.INHALT) for 4 of your result columns and just aliasing them.  That's going to give you the same value for those 4 columns.  Seems you're looking for some kind of grouping, but you need to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your output doesn't make any sense at all. It contains data from various rows with no explanation why.

Comment: It looks like each row in the ARTIKEL table relates to many rows in the FDDATEN table.  If you update your question to include the table definitions then the nice folks here will be better able to provide a solution.  I'm guessing there's a field on the FDDATTEN table that identifies which row holds the Herstellername, which holds the Typenummer, etc.  For what it's worth, I suspect a 'pivot' will help you (search for "sql server pivot").

Comment: Have you looked at STUFF() - I used it for a similar issue and it worked great.  Just search on SQL STUFF to get info.

Comment: First of all many thanks for your help. As I've already written, I haven't really warmed up with sql yet. So I'm sorry that some key information were missing. I will try to provide the table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the table FDDATEN has an additional field TYP where you store the fact weither a row is e.g a Herstellername, a Typennummer or whatever. Obviously I don't know the correct name for this column in your database nor the actual values to indicate which INHALT belongs to which TYP, but you should be able to adapt this one easily.

The Query you´re looking for is something goes somethin like this

```
SELECT 
        dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL, 
        dbo.ARTIKEL.SUCHWORT, 
        dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTTEXT, 
        (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE SCHLUESSEL = ROWART AND TYP = 'Herstellername') as Herstellername,
        (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE SCHLUESSEL = ROWART AND TYP = 'Typennummer') as Typennummer,
        (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE SCHLUESSEL = ROWART AND TYP = 'Bestellnummer') as Bestellnummer,
        (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE SCHLUESSEL = ROWART AND TYP = 'HerstArt') as HerstArt,
        dbo.ARTIKEL.ROWART
FROM dbo.ARTIKEL
WHERE ARTIKEL LIKE 'E%'
```

If you don't have a column in FDDATEN to identify the correct row for each column you probably can't get this one done.
Or if there are multiple entries for one SCHLUESSEL and one TYP, you´ll get SQL errrors.

Comment: *If* this is the right solution, conditional aggregation would be a much better (performant) solution over 4 subqueries.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. in the table FDDATEN is a colume which identify 'Hersteller' and so on with a Number.

Answer (score 0):

So for later me and others my solution was this:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL, 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.SUCHWORT, 
    dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTTEXT, 
    (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE ROWART = SCHLUESSEL and ROWFDPOS = 1) as Herstellername,
    (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE ROWART = SCHLUESSEL and ROWFDPOS = 11) as Typennummer,
    (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE ROWART = SCHLUESSEL and ROWFDPOS = 21) as Bestellnummer,
    (SELECT INHALT from dbo.FDDATEN WHERE ROWART = SCHLUESSEL and ROWFDPOS = 31) as HerstArt
FROM dbo.ARTIKEL
WHERE ARTIKEL LIKE 'E%'
```